# Pyexcel: do not ignore underscores

Tags: python, string, csv, int, pyexcel

I an using pyexcel to read a csv file which contains entries like

```
1234_5678,,,,,,,
```

This is being read in by pyexcel as 12345678 rather than "1234_5678". Is there a way to force this to be read as a string rather than having the underscores removed.

The way I am using pyexcel is with the get_array function

```
pyexcel.get_array(file_content=file_content, file_type="csv")
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you use to read the csv?

Comment: Provided, I believe it may have something to do with a convention unknown to me that one can use x = 1_000_000 and Python interprets this as a number!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pyexcel issue 138](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel/issues/138) stated the same use case. And it has been resolved by pyexcel-io version 0.5.7+. For example, the following command will do:

```
pip install pyexcel-io==0.5.7
```

On the contrary, if you want to keep the feature instead, you can pass on `pep_0515_off=False` in your function call.